# SQL Joins with one to many relationship - Combine the many into one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product table and a price table where a product can have several price rows. Is it possible to do a JOIN statement that returns one row per product with the price column from each price row where product is equal to the product ID?

Right now I have this:

```
SELECT PT.*, PR.* 
FROM `products` AS PT 
RIGHT JOIN `prices` PR 
    ON PR.`product` = PT.`ID`
```

And if there are 4 price rows for one product, I get 4 rows in response.

Comment: do you mean you want product, price = 1,2,3? with the prices in the same column? or multiple columns for each price?

Comment: @bluefeet Either solution would be acceptable

Comment: I think you can only do something like comma separated prices. Adding extra columns wouldn't work (so far as I know).

Comment: Are you trying to get all of `PR.*` or just `PR.price`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up the wizzbang GROUP_CONCAT function, which does what you want quite nicely (making a delimiter-separated string).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT pt.`id`, 
       group_concat(pr.`price` separator ',') 
  FROM `products` AS PT  
  LEFT JOIN `prices` PR ON PR.`product` = PT.`ID`
  GROUP BY pt.`id`
```